The need for a toggle to enable a user to insert delay between keypress and action in video players and/or how to get such a delay on my own machine
It used to be the case (or at least it certainly seemed to be the case) that there was a 'considerate' delay between keypress and action when clicking GUI buttons (play/pause et c.), or using hotkeys, on digital video players such as Youtube, or VLC, for example.
As a physical product designer myself I am convinced that such a delay used to be intentionally-included in software/webpages/browsers so as to avoid making the user feel overwhelmed/irritated/shocked by the suddenness of an action produced by a microprocessor that could produce instantaneous results in response to a keypress or mouse-button click.
Such is known as an 'ergonomic' consideration or design feature in the field of physical product design and I am sure the same holds true
in software design.
Nowadays there is a unilateral 0ms delay between keypress and resultant action in video players, whether online or downloadable and there seems
to be no way to remedy it!
The same problem exists in web browsers whereby web pages load INSTANTANEOUSLY and the effect is jarring. One might argue
that that is probably due to internet speed but any designer of any product whether physical or digital/software would be sorely remiss for
overlooking such a consideration - and internet speed cannot be the cause when using downloaded software.
It seems to me that the 'push' for speed in all things digital has created this wanton disregard for what I will term 'considerate' or 'ergonomic'
delay between keypress and action in UI design and I regard it as ridiculous, certainly irritating and even harmful.
'Over-fast' things can easily annoy a user making them feel that they are out of control of the thing they are using, and the fact that I can't get
that delay, which allowed me to retrieve my fingertip from the button and 'compose' myself slightly before the action I sought was produced,
back is a really big problem.
It makes using any video player a nightmare to use. Surely someone on this forum knows what I am talking about.
I want to inform the wider 'software-/web- developing' industry that their disregard for this issue is a big problem. I want to be able to
at least toggle such a delay back into existence, even if just for myself, but I am sure that including of such a toggle as a generally-added
function to such user interfaces would be advantageous to millions of other users too.
Who do I consult about such a widespread problem? Can I produce a delay even on my own computer somehow? I've tried every toggle related to
such things in windows regedit but NONE of them produces the desired result.
I can find no other reference to this problem online - it seems that everyone is wrapped up in a mindless quest for 'speeeeed'...
Thank you in advance for your help people!
James :)

Sources please.

Every second of loading delay leads to user frustration and significantly less conversion. Earlier we were limited by touch screen technology which was not sensitive enough or bluetooth which wasn't fast enough. Even if we had the technology, they were not portable enough or economically viable. However, currently we are not limited by the tech speed but human limitations.
